# Static IP on LAN and DHCP on WLAN on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp, static-ip

I use a Netbook with LAN and WLAN. On LAN I need a static IP for dev. On WLAN I dont can use a static IP because I am in different WLANs.

Here is my interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet static
address 192.168.178.202
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.178.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.178.1

auto wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet dhcp
```

This config works for LAN, but I cant connect to any WLAN. If I comment everything out and restart the PC I can connect to every WLAN.

Where is my bug?

Comment: which Ubuntu version ?

Answer (score 0):

Your wireless card will not know which access point to connect to among the many that are possibly available within scan distance and, more importantly, which you deem secure, unless you declare it along with the password.

I suggest that you amend the interfaces file to something like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet static
address 192.168.178.202
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.178.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.178.1

auto wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid your_router
wpa-psk your_secret_password
```

Restart the interface and see if you connect:

```
sudo ifdown wlp2s0 && sudo ifup -v wlp2s0
```

The -v for verbose should produce output that tells you if you connected.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 should use Network Manager. So, go to the settings. You'll be surprised. Because Network Manager actually creates different settings for each device AND network. Meaning, you can ALWAYS use static IP addresses. Even if you use more than one wireless network with the same device. The list of settings might get a bit confusing though, if you use a number of devices. So, you might want to rename them in the settings to know which belongs where. In regards to IP addresses, just edit the settings for the according network and device and go to the IP4 settings tab. Switch from automatic to manual and there you go. You can enter the IP address, gateway, network mask and DNS servers. Both, device AND network specific. You'll find settings for "SSID 1" and "SSID 2". So, if you make the according individual settings, you will be able to use static IP 1 for SSID 1 and static IP 2 for SSID 2. Also wired and wireless connections are separated.